# "Predicting" Perfectly Cyclical Binomial Event Using Multivariate Time-Series Data

Tags: time-series, predictive-models, arima

I have dates for certain binary events all across the country. I have reason to believe that weather has a short-term predictive power with the events. I have collected various weather variables about each event for a week prior to their occurrence and on the day of their occurrence. For a minimal example:

```
temperature,humidity,eventid,relativeday,incident
10,76.9,1,1,0
15,78.9,1,2,0
18,100,1,3,0
16,88.9,1,4,0
23,76.7,1,5,0
22,75.9,1,6,0
21,80.8,1,7,0
9,69.2,1,8,1
71,77.8,2,1,0
82,66.7,2,2,0
79,77.8,2,3,0
78,62.5,2,4,0
74,50.0,2,5,0
72,44.4,2,6,0
79,45.8,2,7,0
68,85.7,2,8,1
...
```

In this example, `incident` is perfectly cyclical; it happens every eight days when `relativeday` is 8, because that's how we have chosen to query the weather data. Also important to note that there may be a significant break in time and place between `eventid` 1 and `eventid` 2 (note the different temperatures), so after an event the model should "reset."

I want to best model whether or not there will be an `incident` based on `temperature` and `humidity`. What would be the best method here?

If the answer is an ARIMA-esque model, how do you address the fact that the events come from different places? Is making all of the variables relative to their value on `relativeday` 1 a best practice? (e.g., the temperature would go `0, 5, 8, 6...` for `eventid` 1 and then `0, 11, 8, 7, 4, 1, 8, -3` for `eventid` 2)

Comment: What is this incident? What are the events?

Comment: @user2974951 I am using ```eventid``` to differentiate between the separate "week before and day-of incident" periods. The incidents/events are failures of certain electronics.

Comment: Since you mention breaks and resetting, maybe a survival model could work here, this would give you a probability of failure for an arbitrary time interval.